# Creating and placing a File in Hadoop Distributed Cache

Tags: java, hadoop, caching, mapreduce

I'm trying to dynamically create a resource and place it in the Hadoop Distributed Cache before my job runs - a.k.a. this is gonna be an automated job which needs to gather several things together (via HTTP) before the mappers execute.

The problem I'm facing is that I cannot put it in the setup phase due to the number of mappers I have running - it puts way too high a load on the server being called. I want to be able to retrieve my resources, write them to a file, and then place it in the Distributed Cache for easy access later.

Big node: I do *not* want to write the file to Hadoop, I'd rather have it local on the node.

```
    // The whitelist cache file
    File resourceFile = new File("resources.json");

    // Create an output stream
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(resourceFile.getAbsoluteFile());

    // Write the whitelist to the local file
    // (this is using Jackson JSON, FYI)
    mapper.writeValue(outputStream, myResources);

    // Add the file to the job
    job.addCacheFile(new URI("file://" + resourceFile.getAbsolutePath()));
```

This runs in the `run()` method of my job, i.e. before the mappers begin - but it gives me a FileNotFoundException whenever I try access `new File("resources.json")` in my mappers.

What is the correct way to create these temporary files, and the best way to access them inside a job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this to put your file in the distributed cache:

```
_job.addCacheFile(new URI(filePath+"#"+filename));
```

where filename is the name that the file will have on the distributed cache.

on Mapper read the file like this:

```
Path path = new Path (filename);
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.getLocal(context.getConfiguration());

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(path)));
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work, `addCacheFile` complained about the file not existing

Comment: try to write your file using this:
`FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(getConf()); 
Path tempFile = new Path(tempFilePath);
FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(tempFile);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your file in the cache like:

```
job.addCacheFile(new Path(filename).toUri());
```

In the mapper, it should be fetched like:

```
Path[] localPaths = context.getLocalCacheFiles();
```

Ideally, the best way to keep files in hdfs. There is a very good example given [here](http://wpcertification.blogspot.in/2014/07/using-distributedcache-with-mapreduce.html).

I have not tested the code in the example.

Comment: Yeah, it's easy to keep it in HDFS. But the point is that I don't have the ability to copy it to Hadoop in advance.

Comment: You can do that programatically at runtime and place the file into hdfs. or use the first approach given in my solution.

Comment: How is `new Path(filename).toUri()` different to `new URI(file.getAbsolutePath())`?